# External JS sometimes doesnt loads in time?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
functionFromAJS();
</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

this works OK most of the time, but on production server, its not 100%. It says that `functionFromAJS()` doesnt exists, which is ok, if the .js is not gets loaded in time. But then what to do?

Comment: Have you tried removing the excess `</script>`?

Comment: just a typo. Means nothing

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Using the window.onload function should not do any difference as long as the script you're embedding is loaded before the function call. Then the a.js file will be loaded before `<script>functionFromAJS();</script>` anyway and you should be able to execute the function if it exists.

Try using:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      functionFromAJS();
   };
</script>
```

So that the function is not called before the document is fully loaded. 
Or if you're using jQuery you can use:

```
<script>    
   $(document).ready(function() {
      functionFromAJS();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: hey, yea it seems ok, buuut... if Im using jQuery, your example wont work, because what if jQuery ITSELF doesnt get loaded? :)

Comment: Well, on a second thought I find it quite wierd that you're experiencing this problem. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that if you're using <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script> that script will be loaded before any code below it will execute/be loaded. the onload and (document).ready functions only waits until all the DOM elements are fully loaded I think. So it's quite wierd that you're having those problems. If the file and function exists and you're embedding the JS file before calling the function it should work.

Comment: @jimutt: Yes, the script will be loaded before the parsing continues. Calling the function later won't make the function exist if the loading fails in the first place, which is the only reason why it wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Guffa Yeah you're right. Didn't think before answering.

Answer (score 1):

If the function doesn't exist, then it's not a matter of the file not being loaded in time, then the file isn't loaded at all.

When the browser encounters a script tag for loading a file, then it will stop the parsing of the page until the file has been loaded, or until the file fails to load. The `functionFromAJS` will never be called before the browser has completed the attempt to load the file.

If the file fails to load, then there isn't much you can do. You can check if the function exists before you call it to avoid the error. You could even try to load the script again, but if it failed the first time then it's likely that it will still fail.